# onsen UIのradio buttonにおいてcssが効かない

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

monaca及びonsen uiを使用して開発をしておりますが、なぜかラジオボタンのcssがうまく機能しません。
ラジオボタンが円丸のもののままで、またlabelが機能しません。
以下がコードになりますが、修正点ご教示頂ければ幸いです。
初歩的な質問で恐縮ですが、宜しくお願い申し上げます。

```
<ons-template id="radio.html">
<ons-page id="radio-page">
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">radio</div>
  </ons-toolbar>
  <ons-list>
    <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">
      <label class="radio-button">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" checked="checked" onClick="radio()">
        <div class="radio-button__checkmark"></div>
        radio1
      </label>
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item>
      <label class="radio-button">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" onClick="radio()">
        <div class="radio-button__checkmark"></div>
        radio2
      </label>
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item>          
      <label class="radio-button">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" onClick="comment()">
        <div class="radio-button__checkmark"></div>
        その他
      </label>
      <div id="comment"></div>
    </ons-list-item>
  </ons-list>
</ons-page>
```

[image: 表示状態]

Comment: どのようなCSSを指定して、どのようなプラットフォームで確認しましたか。onsen-ui には関係のない問題の可能性が高いので、通常のHTML + CSSで問題が出るか確認してはどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

新規プロジェクトを作成する際にOnsen UIに関するテンプレートを選択すると、

```
www
  +- components
    +- monaca-onsenui
```

というフォルダの下に関連ファイルが追加されます。
これらのファイルが存在しないとOnsen UIは機能しません。

Monaca IDEの「ファイル」メニューから「JS/CSSコンポーネントの追加と削除」で、
あとから追加することも可能です。

コンポーネントが追加済みで表示がおかしい場合は、
<link>や<script>タグの設定が間違っている可能性があります。
（機能しないのはラジオボタンだけでしょうか？）

Comment: ご回答いただきまして、ありがとうございました。
JS/CSSコンポーネントにおいて、jQuery mobileからjQueryに変更したら正常に動作しました。jQuery mobileでは不具合があるのでしょうか？